# Format date to secounds

Tags: ios, objective-c, date

Background: I have dates stored in files.

What I would like to do: I would like to take the difference between two dates in seconds. I  can't find any way to do it. My date format looks like that:

`2015-23-02-12-23-43`

Comment: what do you mean by time in second. Please at least post a question with full of description what actually happen what you try to attempt and what kind of output you get.

If you have no time or not able to explain your issue how can you get it's solutiuon

Comment: I store dates in a file. I want to compare the dates and count the difference between them. So i want to convert the date to seconds so i can count the difference between two dates. @NitinGohel

Comment: So you want total seconds, not year/month/day/hours/minutes/seconds?

Comment: You need to state your need clearly and coherently, or delete your question.

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify what you are asking for.

Comment: I have done it now @DuncanC

Comment: Your question is still not at all clear. Here's what I think you are saying: "I have date strings stored in files. Here is an example: `2015-23-02-12-23-`. Here is what the date formatter that creates these dates looks like: `[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss"]`. I need to compare dates, so I would like to convert them to seconds. Please explain how I could do that. " If that is what you are asking, please edit your question to reflect that and I'll answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:EnterYourStringHere];
NSString *str = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:string1];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute) fromDate:date];
NSInteger hour = [components hour];
NSInteger minute = [components minute];
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is seconds then use

```
NSTimeInterval dateInterval = [date timeIntervalSince1970];
```

Then

```
NSString secondsString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.0f", dateInterval];
```

### EDIT:

If you have a file full of date strings that look like your example, `2015-23-02-12-23`, then you could use code like this:

```
NSDateFormatter *myFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[myFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss"];

//an example - you'll read from your file
NSString *aDateString = @"2015-23-02-12-23"; 

NSDate aDate = [myFormatter dateFromString: aDateString];

NSTimeInterval dateSeconds = [aDate timeIntervalSince1970];
```

That will give you dateSeconds as a double precision floating point number, which is the norm for numeric date calculations since it deals with fractions of seconds. You can then do numeric comparisons of date's time intervals.

Note that most UNIX systems use the numeric values returned by the `timeIntervalSince1970` method, but Mac and iOS uses numeric date values returned by the method `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate`. The two methods have different "epoch dates", or dates where they start counting from zero.

```
timeIntervalSince1970 uses midnight on Jan 1, 1970 (GMT)
timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate uses midnight on Jan 1, 2001 (GMT)
```

Which you use is up to you, just be sure to use the same method in all cases.

By the way, your date string format is horrible. having all those 2 digit numbers separated by dashes doesn't give the reader any way to tell apart month/day/hours/minutes/seconds. It's all a jumble. You'd be much better off using a standard date format.

In the US it's common to display dates in the form mm/dd/yyyyy (or yyyy/mm/dd, or even yyyy/dd/mm), and times as hh:mm:ss, so in "mm/dd/yyyyy hh:mm:ss" format you'd get:"09/02/2015 13:09:39" (I'm using human-readable date format strings for discussion, not those intended to set up a date formatter.)

Comment: I want to convert a date with this format `2015-09-02-13-09-39` to seconds.